# Avoid notification "kdeinit5 closed unexpectedly" in Plasma 5.14 when starting Dolphin

Tags: kde, kubuntu, plasma5, dolphin

After upgrading Kubuntu from 18.04 to 18.10 and that to Plasma 5.14.5 through the "backports" PPA I am lucky enough to face almost no bugs, except annoying notifications saying "kdeinit5 closed unexpectedly"

[image]

[image]

It happens when I take some normal actions in Dolphin: start a new  window, new tab, split, refresh.

It seems to me that those actions are related to the Dolphin *window*; creating a new folder or deleting something doesn't trigger the error.

I read [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/kdeinit5.8.html) that kdeinit5 is a process launcher that executes KDE programs and kdeinit loadable modules (KLMs) starting them more
       efficiently. Using kdeinit5 to launch KDE applications makes starting a typical KDE application a couple times faster and reduces memory consumption by a substantial amount. - But as far as I can tell only Dolphin reports a problem with that.

I have not noticed Dolphin operation or that of any part of the desktop being affected at all by this, I would just like to avoid seeing those notifications.

Of course, I would like to have a solution that would avoid the error in the first place, but - if that is not possible until a future update etc - I am mainly asking here for a way to simply make those notifications go away.

---

I don't know how to debug this, or if the following is useful, but running `kdeinit5 dolphin` the file manager starts with the usual error while in terminal I get this:

```
~$ Trying to convert empty KLocalizedString to QString.
qt.accessibility.core: Cannot create accessible child interface for object:  PlacesView(0x55d3d75565c0)  index:  14
kdeinit5: Got EXEC_NEW '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kf5/kio/trash.so' from launcher.
kdeinit5: preparing to launch '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kf5/kio/trash.so'
kdeinit5: Got EXEC_NEW '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kf5/kio/file.so' from launcher.
kdeinit5: preparing to launch '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kf5/kio/file.so'
kdeinit5: Got EXEC_NEW '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kf5/kio/file.so' from launcher.
kdeinit5: preparing to launch '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kf5/kio/file.so'
kdeinit5: Got EXEC_NEW '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kf5/kio/thumbnail.so' from launcher.
kdeinit5: preparing to launch '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kf5/kio/thumbnail.so'
kf5.kio.trash: Root trash dir "/media/cip/DEPO/.Trash" exists but didn't pass the security checks, can't use it
kf5.kio.trash: Directory "/media/cip/DEPO/.Trash-1000" exists but didn't pass the security checks, can't use it
Qt: Session management error: networkIdsList argument is NULL
Could not find video stream
decodeVideoFrame() failed: frame not finished
KCrash: crashing... crashRecursionCounter = 2
KCrash: Application Name = kdeinit5 path = /usr/bin pid = 12077
KCrash: Arguments: /usr/bin/kdeinit5 thumbnail local:/run/user/1000/klauncherFKnizM.1.slave-socket local:/run/user/1000/dolphinFjEuPw.5.slave-socket 
KCrash: Attempting to start /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/drkonqi from kdeinit
sock_file=/run/user/1000/kdeinit5__0
kdeinit5: Got EXEC_NEW '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/drkonqi' from wrapper.
kdeinit5: preparing to launch '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/drkonqi'
kdeinit5: Got EXEC_NEW '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kf5/kio/thumbnail.so' from launcher.
kdeinit5: preparing to launch '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kf5/kio/thumbnail.so'
Qt: Session management error: networkIdsList argument is NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

kf5-kio-* version 5.59.0-2.fc29 fixes this issue. Finally got the update and all those very annoying messages are gone.

[Bug 1746465 - kdeinit5 closed unexpectedly repeatedly](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1746465)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and solved it by installing xdg-desktop-portal-kde.

Answer (score -1):

No need to mess with kde things. Your problem is crash notification, simply disable it.
Right click notifications icon > Configure Event Notifications & Actions > Click Configure under Applications section > Select Plasma Workspace > Click Configure Events > In the given list, select Application Crash > Disable "Show a message in a popup" checkbox.

Comment: This hides the symptom of the crash, it doesn't fix the cause, `kdeinit5` still crashes but it's just not shown. And when other programs crash besides `kdeinit5`, you'll not be notified.